# Which Outsider features and traits does the Apotheosis class feature grant?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, prestige-class

According to the Apotheosis class feature of the Knight of the Sacred Seal prestige class, found in Tome of Magic, "your type changes to outsider, and you gain the native subtype (see the perfect self monk class feature).  You also gain damage reduction 10/magic."  Now, my confusion is that I am unsure which specific features and traits that this feature grants.  This feature also seems to repeat what this feature encompasses since the perfect self class feature also grants damage reduction 10/magic so the wording of this feature seems unclear as to what it really grants.

Answer (score 7):

#### Short Version

You get Darkvision out to 60 feet, proficiency with all simple and martial weapons, and potentially proficiency with shields (if you have proficiency with any kind of armor). Interestingly, as written, this would include tower shields, but [using a tower shield is always a bad idea](//rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48555/4563).

#### Long Version

You gain the [traits, but not the features, of the Outsider type](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#outsiderType) as well as the [the Native subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#nativeSubtype).

The Outsider type has many traits, but two of them (inability to be raised from the dead and lack of need to eat or sleep) are eliminated by the Native subtype. Furthermore, Outsiders are said to be proficient in any weapons or armor mentioned in their monster entries, but as a PC race you almost certainly do not have any such weapons or armor.

To wit:

> #### Outsider traits
>
> - Darkvision out to 60 feet.
> - <s>Unlike most other living creatures, an outsider does not have a dual nature—its soul and body form one unit. When an outsider is slain, no soul is set loose. Spells that restore souls to their bodies, such as raise dead, reincarnate, and resurrection, don’t work on an outsider. It takes a different magical effect, such as limited wish, wish, miracle, or true resurrection to restore it to life. An outsider with the native subtype can be raised, reincarnated, or resurrected just as other living creatures can be.</s>
> - Proficient with all simple and martial weapons <s>and any weapons mentioned in its entry</s>.
> - <s>Proficient with whatever type of armor (light, medium, or heavy) it is described as wearing, as well as all lighter types. Outsiders not indicated as wearing armor are not proficient with armor.</s> Outsiders are proficient with shields if they are proficient with any form of armor.
> - <s>Outsiders breathe, but do not need to eat or sleep (although they can do so if they wish). Native outsiders breathe, eat, and sleep.</s>

> #### Native subtype
>
> - A subtype applied only to outsiders. These creatures have mortal ancestors or a strong connection to the Material Plane and can be raised, reincarnated, or resurrected just as other living creatures can be. Creatures with this subtype are native to the Material Plane (hence the subtype’s name). Unlike true outsiders, native outsiders need to eat and sleep.

I crossed out the sections of the Outsider traits that are undone by the Native subtype and by being a PC.

Comment: Hmm. Not quite sure if "proficient with shields" really includes tower, or if I'm just looking at all the cases where it doesn't and assuming a more general rule than actually exists.

Comment: @TuggyNE Basically everything ever that grants shield proficiency is explicit about “(but not tower shields)” but this isn’t. That’s my basis for the claim. Tower shields are certainly still *shields*, after all.

Comment: ...And all those exotic shields, too?

Comment: @HeyICanChan As I remember them, the rules for exotics shields are pretty wonky, but I didn't feel like pulling out *Races of Stone* for an aside. Some of those shields were decent I think?